# How do I use the cstring library file in C++?

Tags: string, class

I'm trying to use cstring.
I have both

```
#include <cstring>

#include <string>
```

in my class in progress.

When I try to compile, GNU gives messages that what I believe are the functions of the class have not been declared.
For example, "error: '::memchr' has not been declared

What should I do to use this file properly?

Edit: Adding/explaining my code

The project is to make a String class to provide functions such as addition and comparison to strings (though the regular string class is also required). I suspect the problem has to do with a collision between my String class and the library string class, so I'm looking at changing the #ifndef and #define lines.
String.h Code:

```
  #ifndef STRING_H
  #define STRING_H

//#ifndef MYSTRING_H //experiment
//#define STRING_H   //experiment

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class String
{
    public:
        String();
        //String(const char*);
        String(char const*); //
        String(char);
        String(int);
        String(const String&);
        String(char, int);

        void print();
        int getLength();
        String substr(int, int);

        //overloads
        String& operator=(const String&);
        String& operator=(const char*);

        friend String operator+(const String&, const String&);
        friend String operator+(const String&, const char*); 
        friend String operator+(const char*, const String&);
        friend String operator+(const String&, char);
        friend String operator+(char, const String&);
        String operator+=(const String&);
        String operator+() const;
        friend int operator==(const String&, const String&);
        friend int operator!=(const String&, const String&);
        friend int operator< (const String&, const String&);
        friend int operator<=(const String&, const String&);
        friend int operator> (const String&, const String&);
        friend int operator>=(const String&, const String&);
        char& operator[](int);
        friend char* operator+(const String&, int);
        friend char* operator+(int, const String&);
        String& operator++(); //prefix
        String& operator--(); //prefix
        String operator++(int); //postfix
        String operator--(int); //postfix
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const String&);

        //virtual ~String();
    protected:
    private:
      int length;
      char* buf;
};

#endif // STRING_H
```

String.cpp Code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
#include <string>



using namespace std;

String::String()
{
    //ctor
    //cout <<"default ctor called" << endl;
}

String::String(char const*)
{

}

String::String(char)
{

}

String::String(int)
{

}

String::String(String const&)
{

}

String::String(char, int)
{

}

void String::print()
{
    cout << "printing something " << endl;
}

String String::substr(int, int)
{

}

int String::getLength()
{
    string h = "hi";
    //std::strlen(h);
    return length;
}

String& String::operator=(const String&)
{

}

String& String::operator=(const char*)
{

}

String operator+(const char*, const String&)
{

}

String operator+(const String&, const char*)
{

}

String operator+(const String&, const String&)
{

}

String operator+(const String&, char)
{

}

String operator+(char, const String&)
{

}

String String::operator+=(const String&)
{

}

String String::operator+() const
{

}

int operator!=(const String&, const String&)
{

}

int operator==(const String&, const String&)
{

}

int operator< (const String&, const String&)
{

}

int operator<=(const String&, const String&)
{

}

int operator> (const String&, const String&)
{

}

int operator>=(const String&, const String&)
{

}

char& String::operator[](int)
{

}

char* operator+(const String&, int)
{

}

char* operator+(int, const String&)
{

}

String& String::operator++()
{

}

String& String::operator--()
{

}

String String::operator++(int)
{

}

String String::operator--(int)
{

}

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const String&)
{

}

//String::~String()
//{
//    //dtor
//}
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <cstring>`, or `include cstring`? If you have `#include <cstring>`, then when writing your post, click the little question mark in the upper right of the editor box to learn about how to make stuff like that show up properly.

Comment: I do have pound; I just didn't write it here at first because I didn't get the formatting of this site. sorry, new to how this works.

Comment: Is there another message like `cstring: No such file or directory` or `no include path in which to search for cstring`?

Comment: No, just "x method has not been declared" all 22 times.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things in the standard library are in the `std` namespace in C++, including functions like `memchr`. You need to either call it as `std::memchr`, or declare something like `using std::memchr;` to call it as `memchr` instead of `std::memchr`. (There's also `using namespace std;`, but [that's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).)

Answer (score 0):

The `<cxxx>` libraries do not necessarily declare names in the global namespace like `::name`. (They often do, though.)

You need to call it as `std::memchr`.

Other alternatives allowing `::memchr` are to use `#include <string.h>` or write `using namespace std;` (yuck!), but really it's best to put `std::` in front of standard library names.

Comment: Well, I tried std::strlen()
and now GNU is saying strlen() is not a member of std, and I know strlen() is part of <cstring>.

Comment: Yeah, it must be a problem with my project specifically because I didn't get any of these errors when I put cstring on a simple hello world.

Comment: @Rez: If the compiler is saying that `strlen` is not a member of `std`, we'd need to see the *exact* source code that produces the error.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: I just added the class with this problem.

Comment: @Rez:  You have: `//std::strlen(h);`. That's a comment, so obviously the compiler isn't going to complain about it. You have `#include <cstring>`, so the compiler shouldn't complain even if you uncomment the `strlen` reference. If you want to know why the compiler is complaining that `strlen()` is not a member of `std`, you need to show us the *exact* copy-and-pasted source that the compiler actually complains about (along with the exact copy-and-pasted error message). But it's probably a dupe. `#include <cstring>` puts `strlen` in the `std` namespace; `#include <string.h>` may or may not.